# Cannot sign-in Google account on Samsung Galaxy S with 2-step authentication

Tags: google-account, 2-step-verification

I recently use 2-step verification to sign-in my Google account.

But after turning this on, I cannot sign-in my phone since no SMS is sent to my phone.

What can I do to sign in now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you signed up for [2-step verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1056283&answer=180744&rd=1), you may need to enter an application-specific password in place of your regular account password. You can generate an [application-specific password](http://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens) when you are authorizing access to your Google Account. This process takes a few minutes, and you only need to do it once per application or device.

Note: For Android devices running 4.0 or higher, you do not need an application-specific password and only need to submit your username and password. You'll be directed to another page where you can enter a one-time six-digit code.

To check if 2-step verification is on or off, visit https://www.google.com/settings/.

Comment: Using the `application-specific password` helps me sign-in. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Wanted to change my app-specific password. Revoked the old one, created a new one, and kept entering and re-entering it. Phone wouldn't take it. Didn't realize that after upgrading Android, the app-specific password no longer works! Entered my regular password and used the Google Authenticator app to create a 6-digit code. Is this documented someone on Google's help pages?

Comment: Wow turns out the phone itself needs the regular password plus 6-digit code, but the phone's native mail app, connecting to Gmail, needs an app-specific password. Confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time because I had two Gmail accounts on my Android,: one for work and one personal. The process is broken if you have two accounts and you try to apply two step auth on a phone (I have a Galaxy 4 by Samsung).

The solution was to delete my personal account off the phone, do the sign-in process which kicks out an SMS 6-digit code then authenticate (worked). Afterwards you can add back the second account.